# Daemonless Relational Database Management System

Tags: java, ms-access, daemon, rdbms

Does anyone know of a Java compatible Relational Database Management System, like Microsoft Access, that doesn't require a server side daemon to manage concurrent IO?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this db?

Comment: Java desktop client. Concurrent users connecting to a centralized DB. Users don't want the overhead of managing a separate server process.

Answer (score 0):

Without a server process somewhere, you're talking about a database library like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) or [SQLite](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/). They work reasonably well as long as you're not expecting lots of concurrent updates to be performant or stuff like that. Those DB servers that are so awkward to set up have a real purpose…

Be aware that if you're using a distributed filesystem to allow multiple users access to the database, you're going to need distributed locking to work (really very painful; too many SO questions to pick a good one to point to) or you're going to have only one process having a connection open at once (very limiting). Again, that's when a DB server makes sense.